# Facing issue in Woocommerce in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently, I am facing new issue in Woocommerce. I tried to place order but am getting 500 error. I checked the error log it shows like the error below,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_order_number() on boolean
```

I checked `woocommerce_order_items` table order item table the `order_id` is 0 and in backend order grid is empty. If anyone has idea means please tell me to resolve this issue.

Comment: did you migrate, make some actions with db?

Comment: no migration, and I deleted the order id as 0 from the table but same issue

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: yes, your table indexes/options are deleted for some reason. it will be better to find why it occured to not get same in future. compare your table with this one: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description#table-woocommerce_order_items. I'm sure, that `order_item_id` loose `auto_increment` option

Comment: Thanks @SamvelAleqsanyan I'll check

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan order_item_id in auto_increment only. But woocommerce_sessions don't have auto increment option is that problem?

Comment: you mean `session_id` row?

Comment: Yes session_id row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163384/discussion-between-samvel-aleqsanyan-and-jeeva-chezhiyan).